# How to get a list of all tables from the database together with column names

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get a list of all tables and their column names from MySQL (5.2).

At the moment I know that I can see all the table names by simply using:

```
show tables
```

Is there a simple extension to that query that would show me list of table names together with column names (I do not need types)? I am thinking of something like a join.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for [INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html)

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
  [AND table_schema = 'db_name']
  [AND column_name LIKE 'wild']
```

Comment: You can also add the TABLE_NAME column to the query to add the name of the table.

Comment: This answer is simply perfect. I got what I needed, just by using table_schema. Thanks.